# Using LaTex, I want to put **aaaa** exactly below $\cap$

Tags: math-mode

A simple question from beginner:
Using LaTex, when I write `\cap_{aaaa} b`, the subscript, **aaaa**, seen in right corner below  the `$\cap$`. I want to put it exactly below `$\cap$`. can you help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either the `\underset` command from `amsmath` or the normal operator `\bigcap` might be what you are looking for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\underset{aaaa}{\cap} \qquad \text{or maybe}\qquad \bigcap_{aaaa}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If between $...$  as asked a big operator alone would not work either as the limits are still put to the side!

Comment: @FrankMittelbach True, of course. The `\underset` was my first answer, then I added the second part because I thought _that_ was (possibly) what the OP actually needed. I _did_ think about text-style math but eventually decided to wait for feedback.